# Updating an atom with a single value

Tags: concurrency, clojure, atomic

I have a number of atoms in my code where a common requirement is to update them to a new value, regardless of the current value.

I therefore find myself writing something like this:

```
(swap! atom-name (fn [_] (identity new-value)))
```

This works but seems pretty ugly and presumably incurs a performance penalty for constructing the anonymous closure.

Is there a better way?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The `reset!` function should do this.

```
(reset! atom-name new-value)
```

Comment: awesome... exactly what I was looking for!

Answer (score 1):

You can use (compare-and-set atom old-value new-value).

But I find it strange you need to change them so much to uncorrelated values. Can't you use bindings or similar things.

Comment: It's for managing a unit of shared concurrent state across threads so bindings wouldn't work. AFAICS atoms seem to be the standard way of doing this.....

Comment: True, but I am worried about the semantics of a global variable which changes often to a value which cannot be transformed from the previous value. With a binding, you make a snapshot of the "shared" state till the capturing scope is left again. If this is not acceptable then there must be time-bound dependencies between threads and and some kind of inter-thread communication through the atom. I have not come accross a use-case like this, I usualy only have things like config, aggregations, or sessions/caches in atoms.

Comment: Example: timers in a simulation. Different threads may need to read the latest global timestamp, only one thread ever updates it. Update is independent of the previous value.